# Extracting value from ipmitool text file using bash

Tags: bash, awk

I'm using Linux (Raspberry Pi) and bash. I'm using the Pi to pull IPMI sensor info from a Dell iDRAC. I've managed to pulled the sensor information off to a txt file, sample below:

```
Fan1 RPM         | 2400.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 600.000   | 840.000   | na        | na        | na

Fan2 RPM         | 2400.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 600.000   | 840.000   | na        | na        | na

Fan3 RPM         | 2400.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 600.000   | 840.000   | na        | na        | na

Fan4 RPM         | 2280.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 600.000   | 840.000   | na        | na        | na

Fan5 RPM         | 2400.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 600.000   | 840.000   | na        | na        | na

Fan6 RPM         | 2520.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 600.000   | 840.000   | na        | na        | na

Inlet Temp       | 11.000     | degrees C  | ok    | na        | -7.000    | 3.000     | 42.000    | 47.000    | na

Exhaust Temp     | 18.000     | degrees C  | ok    | na        | 3.000     | 8.000     | 70.000    | 75.000    | na

Temp             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | 0.000     | na        | na

Temp             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | 0.000     | na        | na
```

What I would like to achieve to to extract the values in the second column, such as Fan1 RPM value of 2400.000 and dump this to a file such as fan1.txt

I'm guessing this is possible using something like sed, but I'm a bit of a newbie in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you're talking about input with "columns" (fields), the tool you want to use is awk, not grep or sed since awk is specifically designed to work on fields while those other tools aren't.

```
$ awk -F' *[|] *' '$1=="Fan1 RPM"{print $2}' file
2400.000

$ awk -F' *[|] *' '($1=="Inlet Temp") && ($7 >= 3) {print $6, $9, $10}' file
-7.000 47.000 na
```

or just to convert to a CSV so it can be read by Excel, etc.:

```
$ awk -F' *[|] *' -v OFS=',' 'NF{$1=$1;print}' file
Fan1 RPM,2400.000,RPM,ok,na,600.000,840.000,na,na,na
Fan2 RPM,2400.000,RPM,ok,na,600.000,840.000,na,na,na
Fan3 RPM,2400.000,RPM,ok,na,600.000,840.000,na,na,na
Fan4 RPM,2280.000,RPM,ok,na,600.000,840.000,na,na,na
Fan5 RPM,2400.000,RPM,ok,na,600.000,840.000,na,na,na
Fan6 RPM,2520.000,RPM,ok,na,600.000,840.000,na,na,na
Inlet Temp,11.000,degrees C,ok,na,-7.000,3.000,42.000,47.000,na
Exhaust Temp,18.000,degrees C,ok,na,3.000,8.000,70.000,75.000,na
Temp,na,,na,na,na,na,0.000,na,na
Temp,na,,na,na,na,na,0.000,na,na
```

Comment: possibly not relevant for this particular data (probably only sensor name would be involved), but if you're outputting csv, you need to check for any special characters like commas in the fields, and escape them appropriately. If the data is being obtained with `ipmitool` its `-c` option may be able to produce csv directly

Answer (score 1):

Grep for the value and cut it.

```
grep "Fan1 RPM" input_file | cut -d'|' -f2 > fan1.txt
```

You could also pipe it via `tr -d ' '` or `tr -d '[:space:]` to remove (white-)spaces.

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you. Are you able to show a full example for removing the white space element? I'm not 100% sure where the pipe etc would go.

Thanks again

Comment: `grep "Fan1 RPM" input_file | cut -d'|' -f2 | tr -d '[:space:]' > fan1.txt`

Answer (score 1):

ipmitool -I lanplus -H BMC_IP -U BMC_USER -P BMC_PASS sensor reading 'Fan1 RPM'|awk '{print $NF}'

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/Fan1 RPM +\| +[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/.* /,"",val);print val}'  Input_file
```